# Make Links - Object Data Causes wild results

Tags: modeling

I have several low poly objects and one high-poly and want to apply the high-poly now that the simulation is in a state where it looks good for my single frame render.  However, when I use the Object Data (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> ), they all go wild.

I have zeroed out the scale and transformations for both the high and low objects, and for the life of me can't find the problem.  I am new to Blender, but I understand to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>  and set the final objects to match their resting scale and location.[image]
[image]

UPDATE: I have since figured out they all their origin set incorrectly, so now they all show up in the same place, but they do not rotate to match.  Any ideas there?

Comment: the position and scale of many of the objects change in a huge way, and several just seem to disappear.  I will try and get a screen shot later today.

Comment: I have added the images.  Now they all disappear.  This is so frustrating!

Comment: Is there physics sim involved?

Comment: It was a bit too large for the method you mentioned, but I put it in dropbox.
[link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/kkwp1244ia37ceb/Can%20Pile.blend?dl=0

Comment: Hoping someone knows and can help me here.  I am seriously trying not to head back to Modo and just do it in there, as I need to move away from that platform and learn Blender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not disappeared, but they are all at the same place as HiPoly :)

Problem here is you applied Rot and Loc, that are zero now for each object origin, but their Object data are not. That means if you Ctrl+L > Object Data to each object it copy exactly the same.

To fix Location is not a problem just select all, search for **Set Origin** > Origin to Geometry. But how to restore Rotation I don't know.

If you have a version before applied transform, would be better.

Comment: If objects are cylinders, local z axis can be gained from ends.

Comment: @sed: How did you solve rotation?